# How to enable iOS Stack Smashing Protection in a Nativescript project?

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-cli

How can I build a Nativescript iOS app with stack smashing protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't really need the native Stack Smashing Protection for a NativeScript application where all your code is JavaScript.

Please refer the [blog post here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/secure-your-mobile-app-protecting-the-code) on **Secure Your Mobile App - Episode One (Protecting the Code)** to learn the different techniques to protect your JavaScript code against any vulnerabilities.